# how to have padding "/" for date search in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, date, uisearchbar

I am unable to get the logic for having a `"/"` padded after a date and month is entered.
How can i get a `"/"` padded after i enter dd and then `"/"` on entering MM
I am using the method shouldCharactersInRange.